# What is the process of connecting two molecules under removal of one molecule of water?

Tags: water

> Certain molecules can be joined by the removal of water in a process called:
>
> 1. Hydration.
> 2. Hydrolysis.
> 3. Neutralization.
> 4. Condensation.

I know that the process of hydration is defined as, "A compound produced by combining a substance chemically with water."

The process of hydrolysis is defined as, "The chemical breakdown of a compound due to reaction with water."

Neutralization is a chemical reaction in which an acid and a base react quantitatively with each other.

Condensation is the conversion of a vapor or gas to a liquid.

The answer is most likely (1), but I'd like some feedback and explanation of these definitions!

Comment: Not that kind of condensation.

Comment: Oops, then what is it?

Comment: Is this an example of a condensation reaction?  A simple example is the condensation of two amino acids to form a peptide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it is a *removal* of water, it cannot be hydration which is defined as the *addition* of water.

Similarly, *hydrolysis* includes the *addition* of water to something so that it degrades in some way.

*Neutralisation* does indeed generate water, but not always one molecule per reaction equivalent (can be two or three) and you do not connect molecules but ions.

*Condensation* not only has its physical definition you stated but it also means (in a chemical sense) connecting two molecules under formal exclusion of one molecule of water.

Note that in many to most processes, the water exclusion is entirely formal and what *actually* is excluded is something like $\ce{H2PO4-}$.